# Trensalte the pop up of close appointment

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming

I am working in Dynamics 365 (D365), and I would like to modify the label of the "Close Activity" pop-up. Specifically, I want to change the label associated with the button named "[Button_label_CloseActivity]."

I attempted to export the translation settings for the Activity entity, but I could not locate the label that I need to modify.